# How to Implement Word Level in google / diff-match-patch C#

Tags: google-diff-match-patch

I am trying to implement word level matches in Google Diff Match Patch, but it is beating me up.

The result I get is:

```
 =I've never been =|-a-|=t=|= th=|-e-|=se places=|
 =I've never been =|=t=|+o+|= th=|+o+|=se places=|
```

The result I want is:

```
 =I've never been =|-at these-|= places=|
 =I've never been =|+to those+|= places=|
```

The documentation says:

> make a copy of diff_linesToChars and call it diff_linesToWords. Look
>   for the line that identifies the next line boundary: lineEnd =
>   text.indexOf('\n', lineStart);

In the c# version, I found the line to change in diff_linesToCharsMunge, which I changed to:

```
lineEnd = text.Replace(@"/[\n\.,;:]/ g"," ").IndexOf(" ", lineStart);
```

However, there is no change in granularity -it still finds differences at character level.

I am calling:

```
List<Diff> differences = diffs.diff_main(linepair.Original, linepair.Corrected, true);
diffs.diff_cleanupSemantic(differences);
```

I have stepped through to make sure that it is hitting the change I made (incidently, there is a hardcoded minimum of 100 characters before it kicks in).

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am stuck with same problem. Could yo post the code here if you have managed to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a sample dotnet project with diffmatch program. Its probably older version of DiffMatchPatch file but the word and lines work.

[DiffMatchPatchSample](https://github.com/niketh90/DiffMatchPatch)

For your above sample text ,I get below output.

> at these | to those

Comment: Thank you very much, Niketh. I actually gave up on it and moved onto something else. Now you have a solution, I will take another look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem in `php`'s version of this library and found a solution [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160110201643/https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/LineOrWordDiffs).

You just have to make a copy of `linesToChars` function called `linesToWords`

Here's How I did it

```php
$dtk = new DiffToolkit();

$a = $dtk->linesToWords($old ,$new);
$lineText1 = $a[0];
$lineText2 = $a[1];
$lineArray = $a[2];

$diffs = $dmp->diff_main($lineText1, $lineText2);
$dtk->charsToLines($diffs ,$lineArray );
```